# How do I get a white WPF ComboBox DropDown arrow color?

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, drop-down-menu

I am trying to work out a style for a `ComboBox` that has a navy background with white text, so I want the drop down arrow to be white also (the xaml I have so far is below).

```
  <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource headerBrush}"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource headerBorderBrush}"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="21"/>
     <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  </Style>
  <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  </Style>
```

ADDED code to set the `ControlTemplate`?

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Fill="White"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the ControlTemplate of ComboBox and you can see a the Arrow as a Path. So change the Fill property of the Path to your desired arrow color. See sample ControlTemplate here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx

Comment: I don't really get ControlTemplates yet I guess. The target type in that example was a ToggleButton, which got me an exception in the xaml designer. Changing it to a ComboBox seems to have turned the whole control white. Is there something simple I can do to fix that (please see edited code)? Thanks

Comment: If you have Expression Blend, just right-click and choose Edit Template -> Edit a Copy (I think those are right names).  Otherwise you should use Reflector with the BamlViewer add-in to get the XAML out of PresentationFramework.Aero.dll, and clip out the parts you need.

Comment: The problem with your edited template is it doesn't have all of ComboBox's other features.  When you look at the Microsoft-supplied template you'll see it is rather complicated.  Copy their code and make the change you need.